# C# .NET 6 LibGit2Sharp Azure DevOps push fails

Tags: c#, .net, git, azure-devops, libgit2sharp

LibGit2Sharp 0.27.2

Similar code worked in the past with a GitLab repository but now with Azure DevOps the push fails, I've been searching and can't figure out why, tried slight variations, everything works until the push.

Any help would be much appreciated.

```
string azureToken = "xxx";
string azureUser = "pat";
string repoBranch = "main";
string repoName = "xxx";
string tempPath = Path.Combine(@"C:\Git", repoName);
Directory.CreateDirectory(tempPath);

string repo = $"dev.azure.com/xxx/xxx/_git/{repoName}";

Repository.Clone($"https://{azureUser}:{azureToken}@{repo}", tempPath, new CloneOptions
{
    BranchName = repoBranch,
});

await File.WriteAllTextAsync(Path.Combine(tempPath, "Test1.txt"), "test1");

using (Repository repository = new(tempPath))
{
    //repository.Index.Add("Test1.txt");
    //repository.Index.Write();
    Commands.Stage(repository, "*");

    Signature signature = new("xxx", "xxx", DateTimeOffset.Now);
    Commit commit = repository.Commit("Test", signature, signature);

    CredentialsHandler credentials = new CredentialsHandler((_, _, _) => new UsernamePasswordCredentials
    {
        Password = azureToken,
        Username = azureUser,
    });

    MergeResult mergeResult = Commands.Pull(repository, signature, new PullOptions
    {
        FetchOptions = new FetchOptions
        {
            CredentialsProvider = credentials,
        },
        MergeOptions = new MergeOptions
        {
            FailOnConflict = true,
            IgnoreWhitespaceChange = true,
        },
    });

    repository.Network.Push(repository.Branches[repoBranch], new PushOptions
    {
        CredentialsProvider = credentials,
    });
}
```

```
LibGit2Sharp.LibGit2SharpException: failed to write final chunk: The parameter is incorrect.

   at void LibGit2Sharp.Core.Ensure.HandleError(int result) in /_/LibGit2Sharp/Core/Ensure.cs:line 154
   at void LibGit2Sharp.Core.Proxy.git_remote_push(RemoteHandle remote, IEnumerable<string> refSpecs, GitPushOptions opts) in /_/LibGit2Sharp/Core/Proxy.cs:line 2240
   at void LibGit2Sharp.Network.Push(Remote remote, IEnumerable<string> pushRefSpecs, PushOptions pushOptions) in /_/LibGit2Sharp/Network.cs:line 372
   at void LibGit2Sharp.Network.Push(IEnumerable<Branch> branches, PushOptions pushOptions) in /_/LibGit2Sharp/Network.cs:line 240
```

Comment: No solution but maybe you could stop before pushing and try to push from git command line to see if the error come from the push or of what has been done before.